# Countif non blank based on date range

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I'm looking for a way to count only the cell where based on the cell's date value it will check if the rest of the cells' values in the same row is 0 and will return the count.

So in the picture (cell: `I2`) I'm trying to return the count of those only who joined say within 2019 (`A2:A12`) and didn't receive any induction.

[image] [Desired answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZONs.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example with perhaps a screenshot? It is very difficult to understand your question.

Comment: can you please replace your example (screenshot) with desired answers? I think your question is still not very clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @TerryW, I've added the pic. Anyway, I've found another way using SUMPRODUCT and LEFT function.

Answer (score 0):

Where column A is the join date and Columns B through G are the possible introduction dates, you can just use `IF` with logical tests, drag the formula down, and then count the instances with `SUM`.

Try:

`=IF(AND($A2>=1/1/2018, $A2<=12/31/2018, CONCAT($B2:$G2)=""), 1, "")`

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. Anyway, thank you for stepping up. I've found another way.